# broadcasting auth on custom guard using Laravel passport is returning 401 Unauthorized

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, broadcasting, laravel-guard

Getting **401 Unauthorized** on **broadcasting/auth** for presence channel

**Note:** Same middleware I'm using on other end-point with same token and giving me response

here is **channel.php** code

```
Broadcast::channel('broadcast-restaurant-message.{id}', function ($restaurant, $id) {
 if( (int) $restaurant->id === (int) $id) { 
    return [ 'id' => $restaurant->id, 'name' => $restaurant->name, 'image' => $restaurant->image ]; } });
```

**BroadcastServiceProvider.php** code

```
Broadcast::routes(["prefix" => "api", "middleware" => ['auth:restaurant', 'scopes:restaurant']]);
```

**auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admins',
    ],
    'restaurant' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'restaurants',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],
        'restaurants' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Restaurant::class,
        ],
    ]
```

I pass additional attributes in

```
Broadcast::routes(["prefix" => "api", "middleware" => ['auth:restaurant', 'scopes:restaurant']]);
```